# What's the difference between aircon modes Auto, Sun, Snowflake?

Tags: airflow, temperature, electrical

Most air conditioners have three modes: Auto, Sun, Snowflake

What is the difference it terms how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The sun is heating mode**. When the room temperature reaches the set temperature, the air conditioner stops operating until the temperature falls below the set temperature and the starts operating again. When in heating mode, the air conditioner does not cool. This setting is used during cold weather periods, such as in winter.

**The snowflake is cooling mode**. When the room temperature reaches the set temperature, the air conditioner stops operating until the temperature rises above the set temperature and starts operating again. When in cooling mode, the air conditioner does not heat the room. This setting is used in hot weather periods, such as summer.

**Auto is automatic mode** where the air conditioner can either heat or cool as required. It tries to achieve the set temperature by switching from heat mode to cooling mode automatically. If you don't want to change between heat and cool modes when the seasons change, just set the air conditioner to automatic mode.

Comment: terms used artistically. LOL. :) Can use something like "Hell" or "Avalanche" soon. :P

Comment: Is this correct: "The snowflake is cooling mode" and then "This setting is used in cold weather periods, such as winter"? Who's gonna use cooling in winter? @fred

Comment: @VasylBoroviak: My mistake - corrected now.